# A question on open mappings

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space. $f: X \to Y=f(X)$ is open and continuous mapping.
Must $Y$ be a metric space? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What topology do you have on $Y$?

Comment: If I know the topology on $Y$, then I could judge whether it is a metric space.

Comment: Well, how can it be open and continuous without some metric? If you take the discrete topology on $Y$, then any function is open and continuous, and you can use the metric $d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & x=y \\ 1 & x \neq y \end{cases}$.

Comment: Also, the topology doesn't define a metric.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Do you mean $Y$ is a **metrizable** space?

Comment: I'm not sure that $Y$ must be a metrizable space. I just don't agree with copper.hat.

Comment: Engelking says that $Y$ should be a Frechet-Urysohn space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and let $Y = \{a, b\}$ have the topology $\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$.  Define the map $f: \mathbb{R} \to Y$ by $f(0) = b$ and $f(x) = a$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.  Then, $f$ is open, continuous, and onto, but $Y$ is not metrizable.